# Body not Posting in Django Rest API call using Javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, fetch

I am using Django RestFramework API in my Node.js App.
I am using Javascript fetch API to send some data to backend of my Project which is configured in Django.
But the data is not getting posted. It runs fine in PostMan but not using fetch.

my API class is as follows:

```
class ProfileList(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        ProfileObjects = Profile.objects.all()
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(ProfileObjects, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        print(request.POST)
        print(self.request.POST)
        ProfileObjects = Profile.objects.all()
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(ProfileObjects, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The fetch call looks like this..:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/API/', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({data: "your data"})
}).then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Well according to the API class view it should print `{data: "your data"}` but it isn't.
Instead this is being printed out while using fetch call

```
<QueryDict: {}>
<QueryDict: {}>
HTTP POST /API/ 200 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:62136]
```

And when i use this with postman this gets printed..

```
<QueryDict: {'data': ['your data']}>
<QueryDict: {'data': ['your data']}>
HTTP POST /API/ 200 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:62358]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ProfileList(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        ProfileObjects = Profile.objects.all()
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(ProfileObjects, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        print(request.POST) // will not work
        print(request.data) // will work
        ProfileObjects = Profile.objects.all()
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(ProfileObjects, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The main problem was that I was accessing the body using request.POST instead of request.data

Answer (score 0):

The `csrftoken` header should be `X-CSRFToken`, like below -

```
headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}
```

Try this and check, you can see the doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request)

And for parsing the request, in DRF we should use `request.data` not `request.POST`.

Check request parsing in DRF [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#request-parsing)

Comment: are you getting exception in the browser console?

Comment: No I am not getting any Exception on the console. Things which I am returning from API view it gets logged out on the console perfectly.. The only Problem is the data that I am sending from fetch's body part does not come into backend. Rest everything works fine...and the same thing works perfectly in POSTMAN

Comment: Oh i think its because you are using `request.POST`, it should be `request.data`.

Comment: yes that was the mistake...I've Corrected the API class for future users.